# how to query the sqlite using limit

Tags: android

I write the selection query like this:

> 'String selection3 =
>   TriplePayProviderMetaData.ProgramTableMetaData.PROGRAM_LCN 
>                     + " = '" + channelLcn + "'" + " AND " + TriplePayProviderMetaData.ProgramTableMetaData.PROGRAM_START_TIME + 
>                     " > " + " '" + time + "'" + " LIMIT " + " '" + 3 + "'";'

But it says syntax error at limit:

> 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "LIMIT": syntax error:
>   , while compiling: SELECT title, lcn, _id, end_time, description,
>   program_logo, start_time, rating, parent_guide FROM programs WHERE
>   (lcn = '100' AND start_time >  '1327026600000' LIMIT  '3') ORDER BY
>   start_time ASC E/AndroidRuntime(15912):        at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:158)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15912):        at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15912):        at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:330)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15912):        at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15912):        at
>   android.content.ContentProviderClient.query(ContentProviderClient.java:49)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15912):        at
>   com.vovinet.miniepguru.MiniEpgActivity$1.onClick(MiniEpgActivity.java:150)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15912):        at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15912):        at
>   android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:4257) E/AndroidRuntime(15912):
>   at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1280)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(15912):        at android.view.View.dispatchKeyE
>   W/ActivityManager( 1133):   Force finishing activity
>   com.vovinet.miniepguru/.MiniEpgActivity W/ActivityManager( 1133):
>   Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{40630af0
>   com.vovinet.miniepguru/.MiniEpgActivity}'

Answer (score 2):

You are passing limit as String. Limit is an integer value. So remove `"'"` tag from limit.

Also Limit has two parameters

LIMIT 0 , 10

> 1st value 0 show that start getting record form 0 position. 2nd value
>   10 show that get then record from starting position. So it will return
>   1st 10 records.
>
> if you say 10 , 10. It will get 10-20 record form the cursor. As
>   starting position is 10 and no of record is also 10.

You can also check this link
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

**Edited:**
Your query is

> SELECT title, lcn, _id, end_time, description, program_logo, start_time, rating, parent_guide FROM programs WHERE (lcn = '100' AND start_time > '1327026600000' LIMIT 0 , 3) ORDER BY start_time ASC

Basically you are adding limit wrongly

LIMIT is used after ORDER BY cluse ( check the link http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

It should be

> SELECT title, lcn, _id, end_time, description, program_logo, start_time, rating, parent_guide FROM programs WHERE (lcn = '100' AND start_time > '1327026600000') ORDER BY start_time ASC LIMIT 0 , 3

Comment: hello arslan thanks for your quick response.if i am using like the above but it gives the same error` android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "LIMIT": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT title, lcn, _id, end_time, description, program_logo, start_time, rating, parent_guide FROM programs WHERE (lcn = '100' AND start_time >  '1327026600000' LIMIT 0 , 3) ORDER BY start_time ASC`

Comment: THANKS FOR REPLY,by using the above select query how to write query to get the result `SELECT title, lcn, _id, end_time, description, program_logo, start_time, rating, parent_guide FROM programs WHERE (lcn = '100' AND start_time > '1327026600000') ORDER BY start_time ASC LIMIT 0 , 3` like this.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the SQLiteDatabase has a function to do this thing.

public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit) 
Query the given table, returning a Cursor over the result set.

limit  Limits the number of rows returned by the query, formatted as LIMIT clause. Passing null denotes no LIMIT clause.

Please look at [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: hi hubert thanks for your response actually i am querying the data from database content provider.so if i query by the above arguements it gives the compilation error the method query in the tupe content providerclient is not applicable